# When i try to run a sql query in magento adminhtml it gives the data, but i'm getting a magento error some where else

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento

This is my code located in app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\customer\tab\addresses.phtml

```
    $arrParams = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
    $read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
    $query = 'SELECT entity_id, parent_id, is_active FROM ' .    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('customer_address_entity').'
    WHERE parent_id = '.$arrParams['id'];
    $results1 = $read->fetchAll($query);
```

data is correct but when I try to create new customer in the backend it gives an error

```
(SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1)
```

Comment: The question description needs more things: actual code you run to create customer; path to file, where the code is located; scenario how you get to that code (i.e. I go to admin backend, type "/admin/create_my_customer").

Comment: What happens when $arrParams['id'] is empty or not an int?

Answer (score 0):

$arrParams['id'] was the problem. It was null at some other location.

Thhanks